# Chart not labeling entire X Axis (dynamic)

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to display points from 7 files. Each file corresponds to a day, and I am trying to add a button where it takes the last 7 created files and displays them as x=dateTime and y= value. what this code currently does is that only displays the x axis on the left and right side.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
 chart1.Titles.Clear();
 chart1.Series.Clear();
 xAxis.Clear();               
 yAxis.Clear();           
  var Series1 = new Series
            {
                Name = comboBox2.Text,
                Color = System.Drawing.Color.Green,
                IsVisibleInLegend = false,
                IsXValueIndexed = true,
                ChartType = SeriesChartType.Area
            };
            this.chart1.Series.Add(Series1);
            double measur = 0;
            //clear graph          
            string Folder = @"\\Engineer\DI-808\outlooktest\";
            var files = new DirectoryInfo(Folder).GetFiles("*_*");
            string latestfile = "";

            DateTime lastModified = DateTime.MinValue;
            List<string> filesD = new List<string>();

            DateTime endDate=DateTime.Now;
            DateTime startDate= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3);
            DateTime dateToCheck;
            Console.WriteLine(startDate + " " + endDate);
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(file.Name+"before");
                string edited = file.Name.Remove(0, 6);
                //Console.WriteLine(edited+"during");
                char[] csv = { '.', 'c', 's', 'v'};
                edited = edited.TrimEnd(csv);
                //Console.WriteLine(edited + "after CSV");

                edited = edited.Remove(10, 9);
               // Console.WriteLine(edited+"after");
                dateToCheck = Convert.ToDateTime(edited);
                Console.WriteLine(dateToCheck+" date to check");
                Console.WriteLine(startDate+" start");
                Console.WriteLine(endDate+ " end" );
                // if ( DateTime.Compare(dateToCheck,startDate)>=0dateToCheck >= startDate && dateToCheck <= endDate);
                if (DateTime.Compare(dateToCheck, startDate)>=0 && DateTime.Compare(dateToCheck, endDate)<=0)
                {

                    latestfile = file.Name;

                    filesD.Add(latestfile);
                    Console.WriteLine(latestfile+" dweeb");

                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine(filesD.Count());
            for (int i = 0; i < filesD.Count(); i++)
                Console.WriteLine(files[i]);

            string lineData;
            try
            {
                for (int i=0;i<filesD.Count();i++) {
                    readData = new StreamReader(@"\\egvfps1.egv.mapes.local\Engineer\DI-808\outlooktest\" + filesD[i]);

                    for (int k = 0; k < 21; k++)
                        readData.ReadLine();

                    while ((lineData = readData.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (Convert.ToDouble(lineData.Split(',')[comboBox2.SelectedIndex + 2]) <= 0.001)
                            measur = 0;
                        else
                        {
                            measur = Convert.ToDouble(lineData.Split(',')[comboBox2.SelectedIndex + 2]) * 110;
                            xAxis.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(lineData.Split(',')[1]));
                            yAxis.Add(measur);
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            readData.Close();



            this.chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm:ss";
            this.chart1.Titles.Add(comboBox2.Text + "(" + xAxis[0].ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + ")");

            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            //  chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrd.Enabled = false;
            //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            chart1.ChartAreas.FirstOrDefault().AxisX.Interval = 1;
            //  chart1.ChartAreas.FirstOrDefault().AxisY.Interval = 1;


            for (int i = 0; i < xAxis.Count(); i++)
            {

                chart1.Series[comboBox2.Text].Points.AddXY(xAxis[i], yAxis[i]);
            }


            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            //  chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrd.Enabled = false;
            //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            chart1.ChartAreas.FirstOrDefault().AxisX.Interval = 1;
            //  chart1.ChartAreas.FirstOrDefault().AxisY.Interval = 1;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalOffset = 1;

            chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mps33.png)

I know its somewhere in the Xaxis interval type part,but I don't know what values to put in.

Any suggestions helps!

Comment: How does it look when you keep the Interval automatic, ie don't specify one )or set it to double.NaN) ? Also: Could there be a large gap in your data?

Comment: When I dont specify an interval, I can get three of them displayed. Thank you I am getting closer. Im still missing some slots. What do you mean by setting it to double?

Comment: not to double but to double.NaN, which is a special value that will reset chart properties to their default (automatic). This will be the same as never setting it. Any reason why you set IsXValueIndexed  to true? It renders all x-values meaningless! Sometimes needed but I doubt it is a good idea here..

Comment: You're right. it worked when I commented it out haha.I don't know I found the code and it said it was initializing the "axis"